# Asp.net jquery post to ascx: This type of page is not served

Tags: asp.net, jquery

When I'm trying to call an ascx with Jquery post I get:
"This type of page is not served"
I think it's something to do with the IIS not allowing calls directly to ascx.
Is it possible to allow posting to ascx?
I have IIS6.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? User controls are not designed to be outputted independently. While it's possible to define a handler for them that does it, you are likely to be on the wrong way.

Comment: I'm trying to submit ascx back with data using the jQuery Form Plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, .ascx is a control, it is included and rendered in .aspx pages.

So the error is correct, ascx should not be served.

Wrap it in an aspx page like so:

```
<%@ Page %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="scott" TagName="header" Src="Controls/Header.ascx" %>
<scott:Header runat=server id="control1" />
```

Comment: Do you mean create an aspx file and put the ascx in it?

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, in an MVC application, you are actually allowed to load an .ascx by pointing the URL to an Action that returns a PartialView.